# Calculating the time complexity of algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

I'm new to calculating time complexity. I've searched around and I understand the very basics of it. I have the following algorithm, I'm trying to calculate the complexity of for practice. Am I correct it would be O(n)?

Also, are there any recommendations on places to practice this concept?

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        h = {} 
        for i, num in enumerate(nums): 
            n = target - num
            if n not in h:
                h[num] = i
            else:
                return [h[n],i]

Answer = Solution()
print (Answer.twoSum([2,3,4], 7))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, this algo's complexity would be Linear (**O(n)**). Considering there are **n numbers** and the loop in the function runs for n times.